# How to Select By Value or Select All

Tags: entity-framework, linq

How to select either by passed in value or all records if value passed is empty in EF Linq?

```
public Total GetTotal(string cid="")
{
      var res = from orders in db.Orders
      where orders.Date == date
      && orders.CustId.Contains(cid)
      group orders by new { orders.Date } into g
      select new Total
      {
          Orders = g.Count(),
          Amount = g.Sum(s => s.Amount)
      };
      return res.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET is a web app framework, it doesn't have any database access classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. For me this is usually the simplest:

```
var resQry = db.Order.Where(o => o.Date == date);
if (cid != "") {
    resQry = resQry.Where(o => o.CustId.Contains(cid));
}
var res = resQry.GroupBy(o => o.Date)
    .Select(g => new Total {
         Orders = g.Count(),
         Amount = g.Sum(s => s.Amount)
     });
return res.FirstOrDefault();
```

Use LINQ functions; so you can chain two `Where()` clauses if necessary

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to construct a LINQ query from parts, or omit AND conditions, if you use the fluent form. You can add or omit parts as necessary. In the fluent form, every call to `Where`, `GroupBy`, `Select` returns a new query.

What you wrote can be rewritten as :

```
var res=db.Orders
          .Where(orders=> orders.Date == date && orders.CustId.Contains(cid))
          .GroupBy(orders=>new { orders.Date })
          .Select(g=>new Total
                      {
                          Orders = g.Count(),
                          Amount = g.Sum(s => s.Amount)
                      })
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

The `Where` clause is equivalent to two chained `Where` calls:

```
.Where(orders=> orders.Date == date)
.Where(orders=>orders.CustId.Contains(cid))
```

In that form, you can check the parameter value and omit one of the calls if it's empty:

```
var query=db.Orders.Where(orders=> orders.Date == date);
if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(cid))
{
    query=query.Where(orders=>orders.CustId.Contains(cid));
}
var res=query.GroupBy(orders=>new { orders.Date })
             .Select(g=>new Total
                      {
                          Orders = g.Count(),
                          Amount = g.Sum(s => s.Amount)
                      })
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

This technique can be used to build a query dynamically (up to a point(, by using different `GroupBy` or `Select` calls as needed.